# External HD, fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

Okay, so I have this external (USB) HD that is sometimes (read: almost always) connected to my server. I want to mount the partitions on this HD to my own configured mount points, via fstab.

What is the correct magic incantation for fstab entries if I need to make sure the server does not drop me into rescue mode on boot. should the external disk not be plugged in? I have read about nofail and nobootwait but I'm not sure I really understand the implications.

I'm using Arch linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a CentOS7 the `nofail` option in `/etc/fstab` will not drop you into a rescue shell when the device is not connected.

```
/dev/sdx    /mnt    xfs defaults,nofail     0 0
```

Since you did not mention which distribution and version you are using, you should consult the man page of `fstab` and maybe test it a VM before.

You also could use a `udev` rule to mount the disk or use `autofs`.

Comment: OK, I might give that a shot. I'm using Arch as my main OS, updated the question.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer.

Booting the server w/o the disk works as expected. Plugging in the disk mounts it automatically in my /mnt/ mount point. Booting the server with the disk connected also works as expected.